# AngularJS - Reset form clear models

Tags: angularjs

How to reset a form in AngularJS?

```
<form name="myform">
            <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="one" ng-model="one" /> 1
            <input id="Checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="two" ng-model="two" />2
            <input id="Checkbox3" type="checkbox" name="three" ng-model="three" />3
            <input type="button" ng-click="myform.reset()" value="Reset"/>
</form>
```

The above code doesn't reset form. Is there any method to clear all the model's in a form?

I want to clear all the model's in a given form. I have a bigger form in my application, clearing each & every model looks complicated.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to initialize your form data in your controller as

```
$scope.data = {};
```

And then in your reset method, reset the form data like:

```
$scope.reset = function() { $scope.data = {}; }
```

Instead of myForm.reset(), you will have to call your scope's reset method, as:

```
<input type="button" ng-click="reset()" value="Reset"/>
```

Also, in your html access your model like model.one, model.two, model.three.

Answer (score 0):

What i know is, use particular model name with each field. like ng-model="model1.one", ng-model="model1.two", ng-model="model1.three" ....
Then, on button's click, in your respected controller- clear your scope of model like
$scope.model1={};